# MATLAB code for combining .fig files from a folder to generate a video/ animation?

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-figure

I am trying to make an animation from a sequence of figures (.fig) files of MATLAB from a folder in my system. I referred to the questions [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17508/make-a-movie-from-multiple-images-in-matlab) and [here](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/402087-how-to-open-multiple-fig-files-at-once-through-code).
Finally, I have the code `mkvideo.m` :

```
% Creating Video Writer Object
writerObj = VideoWriter('peqr.avi');
% Using the 'Open` method to open the file
open(writerObj);

% Creating a figure.
% Each frame will be a figure data
Z = peqr;
surf(Z); 
axis tight
set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');
set(gcf,'Renderer','zbuffer');
[figures,var] = uigetfile('*.fig','Multiselect','on');

for k = 1:length(figures) 
   Multi_Figs = [var,filesep,figures{k}];
   Op = openfig(Multi_Figs);
   % Frame includes image data
   frame = getframe;
   % Adding the frame to the video object using the 'writeVideo' method
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);
   close(Op);
end
% Closing the file and the object using the 'Close' method
close(writerObj);
```

I am getting the following error

```
Warning: No video frames were written to this file. The file may be invalid. 
> In VideoWriter/close (line 278)
  In VideoWriter/delete (line 213)
  In mkvideo (line 2) 
Undefined function or variable 'peqr'.

Error in mkvideo (line 8)
Z = peqr;
```

I think this code should be able to produce a video once in user interface, I select the files?

It would be helpful if I could get some help to rectify the error in this code so that the animation or video making is possible.

Comment: When you do `Z = peqr;` on line 8, it looks like `peqr` is not defined. Is it defined elsewhere in your code?

Comment: In this line perhaps I think - ```writerObj = VideoWriter('peqr.avi');``` 2nd line/

Comment: That defines the variable `writerObj`.

Comment: Just remove all the code in between the `open(writerObj)` line and the `uigetfile` line. That is code to draw a graph that you don't need, because you already have .fig files with drawings.

Comment: Cool! now the code runs but once I select multiple files and then select the video to play, it says  "cannot import an empty video file?" and also ```Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 364)
Frame must be 434 by 343

Error in mkvideo (line 21)
   writeVideo(writerObj,frame);```

Comment: Do all the `fig` files have the same width and height? If not, you have to set the `Position` of the figure to some width and height that you want the animation to be. Depending on the number of figures and how long you want to show the frames, you could also choose to create a [`gif`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#btv452g-1), which allows you to easily set the delay per frame.

Comment: Thank u, I will try that. It is working now!!